# Alteryx Error generating JWT token with python tool - NotImplementedError: Algorithm 'RS256

Tags: python, jwt, alteryx

I am having issues creating an Alteryx workflow that encodes a JWT token with the RS256 algorithm in the python tool.

Here is my code:

```
#################################
from ayx import Alteryx
from ayx import Package
import pandas
##Package.installPackages(package="cryptography",install_type="install --proxy proxy.server:port")  
##Package.installPackages(package="pyjwt[crypto]",install_type="install --proxy proxy.server:port")
import jwt
from io import StringIO


#################################
table = Alteryx.read("#1")


#################################
print(table)


#################################
id = table.at[0, 'id']


#################################
url = table.at[0, 'url']


#################################
key = table.at[0, 'key']


#################################
exp = table.at[0, 'exp']


#################################
exp = int(exp)


#################################
nbf = table.at[0, 'nbf']


#################################
nbf = int(nbf)


#################################
encoded = jwt.encode({"iss": id, "aud": url, "exp": exp, "nbf": nbf}, key, algorithm='RS256')


#################################
s=str(encoded,'utf-8')

data = StringIO(s) 

df=pandas.read_csv(data,header=None)


#################################
Alteryx.write(df,1)
```

The problem is when I try to encode a JWT using the RS256 algorithm: `encoded = jwt.encode({"iss": id, "aud": url, "exp": exp, "nbf": nbf}, key, algorithm='RS256')`, It spits back out this error message: `NotImplementedError: Algorithm 'RS256' could not be found. Do you have cryptography installed?`

the Cryptography package should be installed since I specified [crypto] when choosing the package name: `pyjwt[crypto]` – source: [Installation — PyJWT 2.7.0 documentation](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installation-cryptography). I also tried installing it separately by adding `##Package.installPackages(package="cryptography",install_type="install --proxy proxy.server:port")` but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for this was documented [here](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Designer-Desktop-Knowledge-Base/Install-Python-packages-via-command-prompt/ta-p/611877).

I simply followed the instruction for 2021.1.4+ and installed pyjwt[crypto]